# Function Calling in Classes PYTHON

Tags: python

the function `application.start()` is being called on starting the app only,
i am trying to call it using the button `but1` but it wont work or execute the function, also i am trying to avoid the function calling on app start

```
import random
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme('green')
app = customtkinter.CTk()

app.geometry('600x500')
app.title("app")

quotes = [""]

class application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ui(self)
        self.run(self)
    def start(self, tok):
        print("executed")
        print(tok)
    def oF(self):
        return
    def sF(self):
        return

    def ui(self):
        title = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="App", font=("", 24))
        quote = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text=random.choice(quotes), font=("", 16))

        slb = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Server ID")
        clb = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Chat ID")
        sid = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=app, width=148, height=28)
        cid = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=app, width=148, height=28)


        tkt = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app, text="Tokens", font=("", 20))
        tokens = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(master=app, width=324, height=200, )

        but1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=96, height=24, text="Start", command=self.start(self, tokens.get("1.0", "end-1c")))
        openf = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=96, height=24, text="Open", command=self.oF(self))
        savef = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=96, height=24, text="Save", command=self.sF(self))

        but1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
        savef.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.95, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
        openf.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.95, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
        sid.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.2, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
        cid.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
        slb.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.2, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
        clb.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.3, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
        tkt.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.475, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
        tokens.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)

        title.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.075, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
        quote.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.125, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)



    def run(self):
        app.mainloop()

application.__init__(self=application)
```

`

I tried many solutions and I tried searching but I can't find any good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at your button setup:

```
        but1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=96, height=24, text="Start", command=self.start(self, tokens.get("1.0", "end-1c")))
        openf = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=96, height=24, text="Open", command=self.oF(self))
        savef = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=96, height=24, text="Save", command=self.sF(self))
```

What that first one does is immediately call `self.start`, then take whatever it returns and pass that as the `command` parameter.  When you pass a function, you just pass the function NAME.  You don't include the arguments.

What you need here is a lambda:

```
        but1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=96, height=24, text="Start", command=lambda: self.start(tokens.get("1.0", "end-1c")))
        openf = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=96, height=24, text="Open", command=lambda: self.oF())
        savef = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=app, width=96, height=24, text="Save", command=lambda: self.sF())
```